# Jquery allow click one time only

Tags: jquery, onclick

I have small jquery code for div slider. 
**

### [DEMO Here](http://jsfiddle.net/e6spC/)

**

First I click on button for display first div. Its Ok and working.

Now I click on one of list item which display on div and its slide and other div display. Its ok and working fin.

But issue is that if I click on list item number of time then div slide multiple time.

i.e. If I click on list item 5 times then div slide continues five time.

I only want to scroll div one time, no matter how many time I click on visible div.

**Here is my code.**

```
    <div>
        <input type="submit" id = "submit" value = "Show panel"/>
        <span id = "showpanel1"></span>
    </div>

    <div id = "slider"  style = "display:none">
        <div class = "panel1" style = "display:none">
            <ul>
                <li id = "divpanel0">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</li>
                <li id = "divpanel1">Pellentesque nec est eget eros placerat imperdiet sed ac purus.</li>
                <li id = "divpanel2">Fusce id dui lacinia, scelerisque dolor vitae, faucibus sem.</li>
                <li id = "divpanel3">Nulla dignissim odio non turpis consectetur malesuada.</li>
                <li id = "divpanel4">Ut vestibulum est quis lacinia sagittis.</li>

                <li id = "divpanel5">Maecenas interdum libero at suscipit iaculis.</li>
                <li id = "divpanel6">Donec in nibh sed lacus ultrices pellentesque sed in purus.</li>
                <li id = "divpanel7">Aliquam luctus eros id semper vestibulum.</li>
                <li id = "divpanel8">Donec vitae felis at leo rutrum mattis.</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <!--
        <div class = "panel2" style = "display:none">
            <ul>
                <li id = "divpanel0">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</li>
                <li id = "divpanel1">Pellentesque nec est eget eros placerat imperdiet sed ac purus.</li>
                <li id = "divpanel2">Fusce id dui lacinia, scelerisque dolor vitae, faucibus sem.</li>
                <li id = "divpanel3">Nulla dignissim odio non turpis consectetur malesuada.</li>
                <li id = "divpanel4">Ut vestibulum est quis lacinia sagittis.</li>
                <li id = "divpanel5">Maecenas interdum libero at suscipit iaculis.</li>
                <li id = "divpanel6">Donec in nibh sed lacus ultrices pellentesque sed in purus.</li>
                <li id = "divpanel7">Aliquam luctus eros id semper vestibulum.</li>
                <li id = "divpanel8">Donec vitae felis at leo rutrum mattis.</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        -->
    </div>


    <!-- Load Loder GIF -->


        <div id = "loader" style = "display:none">
            <img src = "loader.gif">
        </div>

    <!-- QnA Div Start -->

    <div id = "qaslider"  style = "display:none">
        <div class = "mainpanel" style = "display:none">
            <ul>
                <li id = "divpanel0">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</li>
                <li id = "divpanel1">Pellentesque nec est eget eros placerat imperdiet sed ac purus.</li>
                <li id = "divpanel2">Fusce id dui lacinia, scelerisque dolor vitae, faucibus sem.</li>
                <li id = "divpanel3">Nulla dignissim odio non turpis consectetur malesuada.</li>
                <li id = "divpanel4">Ut vestibulum est quis lacinia sagittis.</li>
                <li id = "divpanel5">Maecenas interdum libero at suscipit iaculis.</li>
                <li id = "divpanel6">Donec in nibh sed lacus ultrices pellentesque sed in purus.</li>
                <li id = "divpanel7">Aliquam luctus eros id semper vestibulum.</li>
                <li id = "divpanel8">Donec vitae felis at leo rutrum mattis.</li>
            </ul>
        </div>


    </div>
```

**Jquery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     var firsttext;
     $(".panel1").on('click','li',function (){
        $(".panel1").hide("slide", { direction: "left" }, 1000);
        //setTimeout(2000);
        $(".panel1").show("slide", { direction: "right" }, 1000);

    });

    $('#submit').click(function() {
        $(".mainpanel").hide();
        $("#slider").show("slide", { direction: "right" }, 0);
        $(".panel2").hide("slide", { direction: "right" }, 0);
        $(".panel1").show("slide", { direction: "right" }, 1000);
    });
});
```

**CSS**

```
.panel1 .panel1
    {
        border:1px solid black;
        margin-right:800;
        margin-top:20px;
    }
    #loader
    {
        margin-right:708;
        margin-top:117px;
        margin-left:525px;
    }
    .panel1 ul li:hover, .panel2 ul li:hover
    {
        cursor:hand
    }
    #slider > div {
      position:relative;
      float:left;
      width:500px;
      height:300px;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't queue animation if there is already one in progress - use the [animated-selector](http://api.jquery.com/animated-selector/) to check whether the `panel1` element is being animated

```
$(".panel1").on('click', 'li', function () {
    if($(".panel1").is(':animated')){
        return false;
    }
    $(".panel1").hide("slide", {
        direction: "left"
    }, 1000);
    //setTimeout(2000);
    $(".panel1").show("slide", {
        direction: "right"
    }, 1000);

});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/9gyjg/)

Comment: Cleanest of all the solutions!

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
$(document).one('click', '.panel1', function() {
    $(".panel1").hide("slide", { direction: "left" }, 1000);
    //setTimeout(2000);
    $(".panel1").show("slide", { direction: "right" }, 1000);
});
```

Or

```
$(".panel1").on('click','li',function (){  
if (!$(this).data("done")) {
    $(".panel1").hide("slide", { direction: "left" }, 1000);
    //setTimeout(2000);
    $(".panel1").show("slide", { direction: "right" }, 1000);
  $(this).data("done", true);
 } else {
    //clicked second time 
    $(this).data("done", true);
 }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the callback:

```
$(".panel1").on('click','li',function (){
         $(".panel1").hide("slide", { direction: "left" }, 1000, function(){
             $('.panel1').show("slide", { direction: "right" }, 1000);
         });
    });
```

#### [See the Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/e6spC/1/)

Answer (score 0):

change your javascript to

```
var firsttext;
var is_moving = false;
$(".panel1").on('click', 'li', function () {
    if (!is_moving) {
        is_moving = true;
        $(".panel1").hide("slide", {
            direction: "left"
        }, 1000, function () {
            is_moving = false
        });
        //setTimeout(2000);
        $(".panel1").show("slide", {
            direction: "right"
        }, 1000, function () {
            is_moving = false
        });
    }
});
```

this will cause any clicks while the change is happening to be disregarded

You can also change your event binding to be a delegate and only fire when the panel is not animated like so

```
$(document).on('click', '.panel1:not(:animated) li', function () {
    $(".panel1").hide("slide", {
        direction: "left"
    }, 1000, function () {
        is_moving = false
    });
    //setTimeout(2000);
    $(".panel1").show("slide", {
        direction: "right"
    }, 1000, function () {
        is_moving = false
    });
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply, assign the same class to each element with that click action and once you did your action remove it for the specific element. Using $(this) is extremely helpful here saving alot of code lines:

```
$(".myActionClass").click(function() { 
    /* Do your stuff here*/
    //Now remove the class and the action cannot happen again
    $(this).removeClass("myActionClass");
});
```